# Find a sequence of integers in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, go

I would like to know if there is a better way (in the case my implementation is correct) to find a sub-sequence of integers in a given array. I have implemented the solution using golang (if this is an impediment for a review I could use a different language). If I am not mistaken the bellow implementation is close to O(b).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    b := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    r := match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 1: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    b = []int{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 2: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    b = []int{1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 3: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    b = []int{4, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 4: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    b = []int{4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 5: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    b = []int{1, 2, 1, 2, 3}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 6: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b = []int{4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 7: ", r)

    a = []int{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
    b = []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}
    r = match(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Match found for case 8: ", r)
}

func match(a []int, b []int) bool {
    if len(b) < len(a) {
        return false
    }

    lb := len(b) - 1
    la := len(a) - 1
    i := 0
    j := la
    k := 0
    counter := 0

    for {
        if i > lb || j > lb {
            break
        }

        if b[i] != a[k] || b[j] != a[la] {
            i++
            j++
            counter = 0
            continue
        } else {
            i++
            counter++
            if k < la {
                k++
            } else {
                k = 0
            }
        }

        if counter >= la+1 {
            return true
        }
    }

    return counter >= la+1
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is not correct, try a = {1,2,3}, b = {1,2,1,2,3}

Comment: @shole Thank you for pointing it out. I do not increment correctly **j** when **i** is 0. I will update the code.

Comment: What you're dealing with is standard string search, although with a bigger alphabet. Wikipedia lists a lot of algorithms here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm Some of them might not be easily applicable because they depend on a small alphabet, but you could do some clever things with your numbers to fix that.

Comment: Sub-sequence assumes that items might be non-consecutive. Is it what you want?

Comment: Please let me know if you have updated the code, as from my knowledge, an O(max(a,b)) algorithm should be optimal using KMP, rabin-karp, or other singe pattern string matching problem, which no one's implementation looks alike your code. So I am more interested into how you do the string matching in O(b) using your own algorithm :)

Comment: @shole I have updated the code, also please note that I am not sure that my implementation is O(b) :). If I would be sure of it I would not be asking this question.

Comment: Still not correct, try    a = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, b { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }

Comment: @shole, true, I just found it.

Comment: basically i am not suspecting the complexity of your algorithm. I am suspecting the correctness of it given that it achieves O(b) AND it does not look like those well-known O(b) algorithm

Comment: @shole: I really do appreciate your insight. I have changed the code again. Unfortunately the process looks like poking with a stick in pond and expect to catch fish. In order to be sure that it works I think the algorithm has to be mathematically proven.

Comment: Then it's your part now :)  You have two options: 1. Learn standard string matching algorithm (KMP for your case is perfect) and implement it  2. Try to sketch a proof of your current algorithm, compared to the logic of those standard one, and proof it is correct / wrong.    For complexity stuff, yes your current code is O(b) as `i` will increase by 1 no matter what, while for standard one it's also O(max(a,b)) which is the optimal to reply your OP

Comment: @shole If you make your comment a *response* I will vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Correctness

As discussed in the comment section, there are a family of string matching algorithms, which normally categorized into single pattern and multiple pattern matching algorithm. In your case it belongs to single pattern string matching problem.

From my knowledge, the most well-known algorithm is KMP algorithm which uses dynamic programming, and an alternative named Rabin-Karp's algorithm which uses rolling hash technique to speed up the process. Both runs in `O(max(a,b))`.

However, your code is not very alike to these algorithm's normal implementation, at least to my experience. Therefore I suspect the correctness of your code at the first place. You can try cases like `a = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, b { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }` to see it is not giving correct result.

Therefore you can

1. Abandon current algorithm and learn those standard one, implement them
2. Outline the logic and sketch a proof of your current algorithm, compared it with the logic behind those standard algorithms to verify its correctness

I will leave this part to you

## Complexity

To directly answer your OP:

No, `O(max(a,b))` is the optimal you can achieve in this problem, which is also the complexity of the standard known algorithms mentioned above.

My understanding is that, it actually makes sense as at worst case, you HAVE TO read each character of the longer string at least 1 time.

Your current algorithm is also `O(b)` clearly, as you loop using `i` from 0 to length of `b`, and no matter which condition you fall into `i` will increase by 1, giving total `O(b)`

---

Therefore complexity is actually not the problem, the correctness is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are only looking for a sequence, i would probably convert everything to string type and use the standard strings package.
[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Epc09TsE56)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9", "1, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9", "1, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9", "1, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("4, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9", "1, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3", "1, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 2", "1, 2, 2, 3"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains("1, 2, 1, 2, 3", "1, 2, 3"))
}
```

Comment: What interests me is an algorithmic perspective.

Comment: If i am not wrong, the strings package employs Rabin-Karp algorithm at some point.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution. You could have at least tried to keep the code of the `main` function of the question and only replace the implementation of the `match` function.

Comment: OP had asked for a better way. I don't see anything wrong with this answer as it even turns out all answers lead the OP to a similar implementation in algorithm.